# CSS: select last ordered flex children

Tags: css, flexbox

Given an arbitary number of flexbox children with an inline `order` attribute used for sorting, how would one select the last ordered element in CSS?

```
<ul style="display:flex">
  <li style="order: 4">a</li>
  <li style="order: 5">b</li>
  <li style="order: 3">c</li>
  <li style="order: 1">d</li>
  <li style="order: 2">e</li>
</ul>
```

`:last-of-type` doesn't work on flex children, and the list can be *any* length, so selecting by order index isn't an option. I'm not interested in JavaScript solutions.

Comment: you need javascript to test order values, CSS will not do this :(

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35355253/3597276

Answer (score 3):

The only close solution to this is may be

```
div[style="order: 6"] {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

And this will color the background with yellow for the 6th order, but since we don't know the length of the array, it seems like you'll need some javascript or jQuery with similar selector sintaxis where the number 6 in this case will be a variable with the array's length.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should propose `:first-order`, `:last-order`, `:nth-order` to the workgroup ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@Marin Takanov's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29719382/1522214) answer above, this method will only work when setting the `order` style inline. It fails when hooking into an `order` set in the stylesheet *...which is annoying if you only have access to the stylesheet but not the actual code.*

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li id="o4" style="order: 4">4</li>
  <li id="o5" style="order: 5">5</li>
  <li id="o6" style="order: 6">6</li>
  <li id="o3">3</li> <!-- Fails -->
  <li id="o1" style="order: 1">1</li>
  <li id="o2" style="order: 2">2
    <ul>
      <li id="o2s1" style="order: 1">a</li>
      <li id="o2s2" style="order: 2">b</li>
      <li id="o2s6" style="order: 6">f</li>
      <li id="o2s3">c</li> <!-- Fails -->
      <li id="o2s4" style="order: 4">d</li>
      <li id="o2s5" style="order: 5">e</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

SCSS:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  li#o3 {
    order: 3;
  }

  li[style="order: 3"] {
    background-color: red;
  }

  li#o6 {
    order: 6;
  }

  li[style="order: 6"] {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

JSFiddle:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29719382/1522214

Answer (score -1):

Your code isnt complete. You have to provide a flex wrapper to your divs (display: flex), so that =order:  will validate.
Therefore, .wrapper div:last-child should do the trick.

Comment: are you sure ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGzLer the last-child remains the one from the DOM not the one reordered .so is :first-type, nth-last-of-type(x), ...  ;)

Comment: I think you're right. Not working with CSS. Should I edit my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I implied a `display:flex` parent. Still a shame this isn't possible from css alone.